# How can I view my video card's temperature via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, temperature, amd-radeon

I've finally managed to set up my two ATI Radeon 6950 video cards in my machine, but the cards can get quite hot. Based on the arrangement of my apartment, I want to be able to SSH into the machine an execute a command to find out the temperature. What I have tried so far is this...

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo aticonfig --adapter=0 --od-gettemperature
```

However, when I do that via SSH, I get the following error:

```
ERROR - X needs to be running to perform ATI Overdrive(TM) commands
```

If I turn on X forwarding when I remote into the machine, then it just seems to affect my local machine instead of the remote machine.

Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way to monitor my video card's temperature?

Comment: You could try `acpi -t`?

Comment: Nothing appears when I do that command; is there some special setup necessary?

Comment: If you're using X forwarding when you SSH into the machine (ssh -X), don't change the DISPLAY variable before you run aticonfig.  Setting DISPLAY to :0.0 will override the X forwarding and tell aticonfig to display on the server, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

lm-sensors will display the temp for most new radeons, if using the open source drivers. If the closed drivers need to access X before getting information, try exporting DISPLAY after changing to root and copying the .Xauthority file from the user's directory to root's home

Comment: If the tool is somehow getting the temperature data from the X server, then redirecting DISPLAY will always get the data from wherever it is being displayed and not the system running the tool.

Answer (score -1):

```
DISPLAY=:0 sudo amdconfig --odgt --odgc
```

if your display is the first one